# Hover over div breaks positioning jquery css

Tags: jquery, html, css, hover

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y78a2/

i have a element  like

```
 <div id="hoverdiv"></div>    
 <div style="margin:0 auto;">
    <div class="hover" hovertext="This is div 1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="hover" hovertext="This is div 2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="hover" hovertext="This is div 3">Div 3</div>
</div>
```

`css` look like this

```
#hoverdiv{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
    color: #DDD;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    padding:10px;
    z-index:10000;
}
```

jquery look like this

```
 $(document).on('mousemove','.hover',function(e){   

    var hovertext = $(this).attr('hovertext');
    $('#hoverdiv').text(hovertext)
    .css('top',e.pageY-95)
    .css('left',e.pageX+10)
    .show();

 }).on('mouseout','.hover',function(){       
 $('#hoverdiv').hide();      
 });
```

MY problem is that

1. The `#hoverdiv` is not beside the `<div class="hover">` (Therefore i
   have to user `pageY-95` AND `pageX+10` **but this works not perfectly
   for all screen sizes(for example after using those values its beside for a `1280X720` monitor but not in `1920X1280` monitor i.e i have to use different values for different monitors(screen sizes)! )**.i don't know why is this happening)
2. **The main problem** is that whenever i am **zooming out** `<div
   class="hover">` changes position(coz it has `margin:0 auto`) but
   `#hoverdiv` remains in same position causing it to work unperfectly.

Therefore any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**
THe fiddle is working fine after removing `-95` `pageY` from and `+10` from  `pageX` ...but not on my pc

**UPDATE2**

```
     body{   
         background-color:#e7ebf2;
         font-family: 'lucida grande',tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;  
         font-size:11.5px;   
         margin:0 auto;
         line-height: 1.28;
         direction:ltr;
         color:#333;
         word-wrap:break-word;

    }
#main_body{
     width:900px;
     background-color: rgba(194,206,231,.5);
     padding:50px;
     box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(194,206,231,1);     
     overflow:auto;  
     position:relative;
     top:110px;
     margin:0 auto;
}
```

inside `body` contains `main body` which contains these elements...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I didn't understand where you want the `hoverdiv` to be positioned? `pageY` and `pageX` are the *mouse* position, so your code will have it show up next to wherever the mouse is on the page, not next to the div. Read this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jquery/jquery-events.htm for a better understanding of how jQuery event handlers work.

Comment: sorry to say @CullenJ but suddenly i have solved the problem by miracle but dont know why it happened. i kept the `#hoverdiv` outside <body> tag and it solved my problem but why?

Comment: Very likely this is going to cause issues in other browsers. I would suggest using valid mark-up and fixing the root issue

Comment: Umm... That sounds like a **REALLY** bad solution. You should never have to put elements outside the body tag. It's not W3C-compliant and will likely cause issues with other browsers.

Comment: i have updated the question with my `body` css please take a look @CullenJ

Comment: i have updated the question with my `body` css please take a look @JonathanCrowe

Comment: You shouldn't have your body set to margin:0 auto; instead make it width:100%;height:100%; and put margin:0 auto; on your child container

Comment: Also - i'm not clear on what you are trying to accomplish. You currently have it set up to follow the mouse position. is that what you want? or are you trying to give it a static position on the page?

Comment: @JonathanCrowe suddenly i got another fix!  i have a `<body>` below that there are many `<div>` and also other element(near about 300-400 lines of codes) now when i put `#hoverdiv` at top of all of em . i.e. exactly below `<body>` tag i got it fixed!! but why??

Comment: What is the `#main_body` ID for? If it's wrapped around the `.hover` div's, that's where your problem is. Absolute positioning is relative to the closest parent without default positioning. http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/box-model

Comment: Yes `#main_body` wrap around `.hover` div's .how can i solve this? @CullenJ

Comment: Thanks very much @CullenJ removing `position:relative;` from `#main_body` got it working

Comment: You're welcome! I would recommend reading over the 2 tutorial links I posted; they'll help you solve problems like this in the future. Here's an updated fiddle that solves the problem while keeping the relative positioning of the `#main_body`: http://jsfiddle.net/y78a2/5/

Comment: I added my answer with a better explanation; please mark it as the answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `#main_body` style was offsetting your absolute positioning of your `#hoverdiv`. Here's a fiddle that handles the situation by adding a `position:relative` to your container div so that we can just use the offset of `#main_body` to properly position the `#hoverdiv`: http://jsfiddle.net/y78a2/5/

Comment: as in jsfiddle u seen to have edited my `jquery` and changes `e.pageX` to `#main_body.offset()` now if i have another div(say `#container` with its won padding and style) inside `#main_body` which contains the `.hover` will the code still work?

Comment: Probably not, but you can edit the code to fit your needs. Just make the JS do the math for you, don't use hard-coded values.